# laravel 5 not deleting user record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

All i want to do is simply delete a user form the database.

My Route is a resource as seen below:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

So this should mean that the destroy action in my UserController should be the place for my code.

So my controller action is below:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Now when i click the delete button, which links to /users/destroy/4

it should find the user with id 4 and then delete it.

Instead i get the error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
```

**EDIT:**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
     <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
     <td>{{$user->HWID}}</td>
     <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
     <td class="tools">
       <a href="users/{{$user->id}}/edit" class="user-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"></i></a>
       <a href="users/destroy/{{$user->id}}" class="user-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
     </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, can you add your HTLM form?

Comment: @ThomasSnijder i have added the html now

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it's possible to directly delete a user from your database via a link as you specified in your table.

My work around for this is to first point the user to the show function in your controller. And giving the user an overview of the information of the user itself.

This page contains a form with the DELETE method. Below the information of the user I put a delete button which will submit the form with the DELETE method to the URL: /users/4

Cause the link: /users/destroy/4 is not a valid resource link.

See this link for extra information about the resource controller links: [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Example delete/show page of my own application:

```
{!! Form::model($ManagementUser, array('method' => 'DELETE', 'url' => 'admin/management/' . $ManagementUser->id, 'role' => 'form')) !!}
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            {!! Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'name' => 'name', 'disabled')) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>E-mailaddress</label>
            {!! Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'E-Mail', 'name' => 'email', 'disabled')) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-default')) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Resource Controller, destroy action is handled by DELETE method. Not GET method. Currently you are accessing a route with GET method that is not registered. The following command will help you to understand Resource Routes that you registered.

```
php artisan route:list
```

GET

```
<a href="users/destroy/{{$user->id}}" class="user-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
```

DELETE (You can delete the record by using form and DELETE method as follows)

```
<form action="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
    <button><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></button>
</form>
```

Reference

[Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

[Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing)